# How to install Dropbox 2.6.27?

Tags: dropbox

How to install Dropbox 2.6.27 (published on 04/11/2014) on Ubuntu 13.10 ?
I can't find the installer in the folders I extracted from the archive.

Official link : [Dropbox 2.6.27](https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=114491)

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the tarball from [here](https://dl-web.dropbox.com/u/17/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-2.6.27.tar.gz)
2. Extract it by going to the location where it is stored and right-click to open the context menu and click on "Extract here". For some unknown reason it is hidden(starts with a `.` in the filename), so you will have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to view its files.
3. Open a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and navigate to the directory where you extracted the tarball.
4. To start dropbox, type `./dropboxd`.
5. To start this on system startup, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login).